# Torsion in absolute Galois groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups, torsion-groups

Let $K$ be a field, $K^{sep}$ its separable closure, and $G := Gal(K^{sep}/K)$ its absolute Galois group. What do we know about torsion in such groups? In particular, I am wondering if there is a restriction on the kind of subgroups, or if all finite subgroups can be embedded inside $G$.

If $K$ is a finite field then $G \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$, in particular it is torsion-free. How about $K = \mathbb{Q}$? How about local fields like $K = \mathbb{Q}_p$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Artin-Schreier theorem says that for any field $K$ the only possibilities for torsion in $\operatorname{Aut}(\overline K/K)$ are in fact 2-torsion elements.
See: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf

The absolute Galois group of $\mathbf Q$ does contain 2-torsion elements though, as we can *choose* an embedding
$$\overline{\mathbf Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbf C$$
and act via complex conjugation to get an involution of $\overline{\mathbf Q}$ fixing $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can it make a difference if instead we look at the separable extension (when the characteristic is positive)?

Comment: In positive characteristic, there are no torsion elements at all. That’s part of Artin-Schreier, too.